# Veracity of light field propagation simulation method (Combined Split-step Fourier and BPM)

Tags: optics, visible-light, fourier-transform, simulations, fiber-optics

When trying to simulate light propagation in three spatial dimensions and one temporal dimension I encountered a method given in [this thesis](https://www10.cs.fau.de/publications/theses/2022/Bachelor_B%C3%B6nselLukas.pdf). Here (on page 32), it is proposed to do a BPM within a step of the 1D Split-step method.
[image]
It seems like a naive idea and the author doesn't cite any sources for where he got it, but it is simple to implement. If anyone has encountered this combined method or could tell me about the legitimacy of doing it this way I would be very grateful.[image: 3D propagation scheme. From 1]

Comment: What is a BPM??

Comment: Here, its the beam propagation method, where Fourier transformation along the transverse dimensions is employed.